# Pressing "d." in VS Code auto-inserts "debugger" keyword – how to stop this behavior?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I've come across an unusual behavior in my VS Code setup. Whenever I type "d." in the editor, it automatically inserts the debugger keyword, and I can't figure out why.

**What I've tried so far:**

**User Snippets**: I've checked my user-defined snippets, specifically looking into the relevant language snippet file (e.g., javascript.json), but found no snippets that would cause this behavior.

**Keybindings**: I went into the Keyboard Shortcuts section in VS Code and searched for "d." and "debugger", but didn't find any keybinding that might be triggering this.

**Extensions**: I've considered that an extension might be causing this:

I looked into the Extensions view and didn't spot any recent updates or additions that might correlate.
As a more extensive step, I disabled all extensions and restarted VS Code. The problem persisted.

**Workspace Settings**: I've reviewed my workspace settings to check if there's any configuration that might be connected to the "d." keybinding or the debugger keyword, but found nothing.

**Expected Behavior**: When I press "d." in the editor, I expect to simply have "d." without it auto-completing or changing to anything else.

**Actual Behavior**: Typing "d." auto-inserts the debugger keyword.

I'm at a loss here. Has anyone else experienced this or have any ideas about what might be causing this and how to fix it? Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: use the keyboard debugging to see what command is executed when you press`.`